# How would I pass a primitive instead of an array pointer

Tags: java, arrays, string, pointers, nullpointerexception

I have a school assignment where I need to create a very basic clone of ArrayList in java. It only needs to work with strings and have minimal functionality (size, add, get). This is what I have so far. I realise that there is probably many things that could be improved, but right now I am trying to work on this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at pt2.ArrayListMine.expand(ArrayListMine.java:13)
at pt2.ArrayListMine.add(ArrayListMine.java:32)
at pt2.Driver.main(Driver.java:21
```

I think the problem is that when I call expand() instead of moving the strings from array to backup and then backup to array it is passing pointers, so after I call it I effectivly have array pointing to backup pointing to array. Im not shure if/how I could force it to pass the string instead of the pointer so I am hoping I can get some advice. Thanks!

```
    package pt2;

    public class ArrayListMine {
        private  String[] array;
        private  String[] backup;
        private  int array_size = 0;
        public void ArrayListMine() {
             array = new String[10];
        }


        private void expand() {
            if(array_size == array.length) {
                for(int l = 0; l < array.length; l++) {
                    backup[l] = array[l];
                }
                int new_size = (int) (array.length * 2);
                array = new String[new_size];
                for(int l = 0; l < backup.length; l++) {
                    array[l] = backup[l];
                }
            }
        }

        public int size() {
            return array_size;
        }

        public void add(String value) {
            array_size = array_size + 1;
            System.out.println(array_size);
            expand();
            array[array_size - 1] = value;
        }

        public String get(int index) {
            return array[index];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you are allocating `backup`. So in `expand` you need to do a new on the `backup` for the correct size. You may also want to move that to be a local variable in the `expand` method, as you don't seem to need it elsewhere.

Comment: You haven't initialized `backup` as you did for `array`

Comment: why you did not point which line is ArrayListMine.java:13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array` is null. Because this

```
public void ArrayListMine() {
     array = new String[10];
}
```

is **not** a constructor. **Remove** the `void`. Like,

```
public ArrayListMine() {
     array = new String[10];
}
```

Next, use `backup = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length)` to copy `array` to `backup`. Because this

```
backup[l] = array[l];
```

will also blow-up.

Comment: Thanks that did it. Kinda dumb mistakes, guess im just a bit too tired. Also thanks for the cloning tip.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the back up with the array size before copying.

`backup = new String[array.length];` in side `expand` method before copying to it.

```
public class ArrayListMine {
    private  String[] array;
    private  String[] backup;
    private  int array_size = 0;

    public  ArrayListMine() {
         array = new String[10];

    }


    private void expand() {
        if(array_size == array.length) {
            backup = new String[array.length];
            for(int l = 0; l < array.length; l++) {
                backup[l] = array[l];
            }
            int new_size = (int) (array.length * 2);
            array = new String[new_size];
            for(int l = 0; l < backup.length; l++) {
                array[l] = backup[l];
            }
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return array_size;
    }

    public void add(String value) {
        array_size = array_size + 1;
        System.out.println(array_size);
        expand();
        array[array_size - 1] = value;
    }

    public String get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayListMine arrayListMine = new ArrayListMine();
        for(int i=0;i<=20;i++) {
            arrayListMine.add("test "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

and further you can replace your `for` loop with `System.arrayCopy`

```
private void expand() {
            if(array_size == array.length) {
                backup = new String[array.length];
                System.arraycopy(array, 0, backup, 0, array_size);
                /*for(int l = 0; l < array.length; l++) {
                    backup[l] = array[l];
                }*/
                int new_size = (int) (array.length * 2);
                array = new String[new_size];
                /*for(int l = 0; l < backup.length; l++) {
                    array[l] = backup[l];
                }*/
                System.arraycopy(backup, 0, array, 0, array_size);
            }
        }
```